# Как вести лог ошибок Telegram-Bot python? Как автоматически перезагружать бота при возникновении ошибки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Всех приветствую!
Подскажите, как правильно будет вести лог ошибок Telegram bot'a на python?
Необходима классификация ошибок по критичности или записи о том, что пропало соединение.
Как правильно расставить в коде функции логирования ошибок? Чтобы лишний раз не захламлять код.

И как дополнительный вопрос, возможно ли автоматически перезагружать Telegram bot через батник, во время возникновения ошибки? (функция перезапуска уже имеется, но с inline кнопки).

**Очень буду рад примерам и более подробным объяснениям.**

*P.S. Пишу бота на python с библиотекой TelegramBotAPI и базой SQLite.*

Comment: Ответ на вопрос сильно зависит от организации кода у вас. И даже при этом ответ будет субъективным. В текущем виде недостаточно информации, чтоб сказать что-то конкретное. Если коротко - нужен код вашего бота.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для логирования можно воспользоваться этим:

```
import logging
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.basicConfig(filename='filename.log', level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

А чтобы перезагружать бот в случае ошибок... это надо сторонними средствами его мониторить, может что-то самописное, или поискать готовые решения.

Comment: не подскажите, лог будет только типа DEBUG?

Comment: В этом случае да, но можете установить еще  INFO, ERROR, WARN